# Запуск внешнего wcf сервиса на ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, сервисы

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется некий внешний WCF сервис располагающийся по адресу:

```
https://cunaexchengetest.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc
```

С помощью Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider я добавил его ссылку в проект ASP.NET Core.

Суть вопроса в том, что при запуске ASP.NET Core сервера необходимо запустить функционал, который раз в 6 секунд будет вызывать определенный метод вышеуказанного WCF сервиса.

Логику придумал такую:

1.Создал внутренний сервис

--Итерфейс

```
public interface ICunaLoader
{
   void LoadData();
}
```

--Его реализация

```
   public class CunaLoader:ICunaLoader
    {
        Service1Client service = new Service1Client();//объект WCF сервиса
        TimerCallback tm;

        public CunaLoader()
        {
            // устанавливаем метод обратного вызова
            tm = new TimerCallback(Load);            
        }

        public void LoadData()
        {
            // создаем таймер
            Timer timer = new Timer(tm, service, 0, 6000);
        }

        private static void Load(object obj)
        {
            var service1 = obj as Service1Client;
            service1.LoadTradeLinesAsync();
        }
    }
```

2.В классу `Startup.cs` добавил этот внутренний сервис в метод `ConfigureServices`

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();
   services.AddTransient<ICunaLoader, CunaLoader>();
}
```

Вопрос!!! Как мне теперь добавить этот внутренний сервис (вернее запуск его метода `LoadData()`) в конвейер обработки запросов  ASP.NET Core сервера?

Comment: 1) зачем вам запуск сервиса в конвейере? 2) Вы таймер как локальную переменную указали, когда она умрет - то и каллбек таймера сам перестанет запускаться

Comment: @tym32167 , то есть достаточно того что я добавил этот сервис в `ConfigureServices` ?

Comment: В плане регистрации мне кажется вам надо только зарегать не тип, а уже инстанс класса и зарегать его как синглтон. Но поглядите на ваш класс CunaLoader - он во первых таймер создает не в конструкторе. Во вторых как локальную переменную. В третьих - никогда его не запускает. То есть вам также надо переписать ваш класс, так как сейчас он не заработает.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо коллега.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @tym32167 - показал в какую сторону двигаться.
Значит оставил только инстанс без всяких интерфейсов:

```
public class CunaLoader
    {
        private static CunaLoader instance;

        private Timer Timer { get; set;}
        private TimerCallback TmCallbck { get; set; }
        private Service1Client CunaService { get; set; }

        private static object syncRoot = new Object();


        protected CunaLoader(Service1Client cunaServise)
        {
            CunaService = cunaServise;
            TmCallbck = new TimerCallback(Load);
            Timer = new Timer(TmCallbck, CunaService, 0, 6000);
        }

        public static CunaLoader GetCunaLoader(Service1Client cunaServise)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock(syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null) instance = new CunaDbLoader(cunaServise);
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }

        private static void Load(object obj)
        {
            (obj as Service1Client).LoadTradeLinesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Далее в конструкторе класса `Startup()` сервера запустил синглтон.

```
public class Startup
    {
        Service1Client cunaServise = new Service1Client();

        public Startup()
        {
            CunaLoader.GetCunaLoader(cunaServise);
        }
    }
```

Все заработало как и предпологалось с частотой в 6 секунд.